# Error WSO2 Identity server 5.2.0 dashboard after integrated with API Manager 2.0.0 as key manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently, I'm running the Identity Server and API Manager in same server.

I have an issue where I'm unable to access https://localhost:9443/dashboard
This page shows blank screen.

The `wso2carbon.log` shows no errors.

This happened after I integrated `Identity Server 5.2.0` and `API Manager 2.0.0` as key manager.

Is there any configuration that I missed?

I configured the server based on this documentation:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

Comment: What you are going to access by https://localhost:9443/dashboard ? Have you set port offset correctly ?

Comment: yes. I already set the port correctly. Since I integrated with two WSO, both were using different port.
Identity Server- 9443
API Manager- 9444

Comment: Can you recheck the configurations in step 5 and 6 whether the host and ports are configured properly with offset and try access https://localhost:9443/carbon

Comment: I able to access localhost:9443/carbon and localhost:9444/publisher or store. All works fine. But cant access localhost:9443/dashboard. It just appear white blank screen without error shows in logs file. I also already check the configuration like you mention. This happen after I install key manager to integrate IS and API Manager.

Comment: Cleaned up English, added spacing

Answer (score 0):

We have identified this as a known issue in identity Server 5.2.0 when configuring as Key Manager for API Manager 2.0.0.
Please refer following public JIRAs for more details.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5427

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5250

This issue is fixed in Identity Server 5.3.0 which you can configure as Key Manager for API Manager 2.1.0.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 
But may I know is there another way to integrate IS and API Manager in same server without upgrading both of this WSO2 apps?